# SphinxQL-Query-Builder. PHP Warning: Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=0

Tags: php, sphinx, sphinxql

I started Sphinx on 192.168.1.102:9312, and tried to run a query from my client machine:

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL;
use Foolz\SphinxQL\Connection;

// create a SphinxQL Connection object to use with SphinxQL
$conn = new Connection();
$conn->setParams(array('host' => '192.168.1.102', 'port' => 9312));

$query = SphinxQL::create($conn)
    ->select('id')
    ->from('documents')
    ->match('content', 'вася SENTENCE молодец');

$result = $query->execute(); // here occurs Warning
```

It produces the following output:

```
$ php sphinx.php
PHP Warning:  Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=0 in /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Drivers/SimpleConnection.php on line 54
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/sphinxql/src/sphinx.php:0
PHP   2. Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL->execute() /var/www/sphinxql/src/sphinx.php:17
PHP   3. Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL->compile() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/SphinxQL.php:261
PHP   4. Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL->compileSelect() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/SphinxQL.php:399
PHP   5. Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL->compileMatch() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/SphinxQL.php:559
PHP   6. Foolz\SphinxQL\Drivers\SimpleConnection->escape() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/SphinxQL.php:467
PHP   7. Foolz\SphinxQL\Drivers\SimpleConnection->ping() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Drivers/SimpleConnection.php:191
PHP   8. Foolz\SphinxQL\Drivers\SimpleConnection->connect() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Drivers/SimpleConnection.php:80
PHP   9. mysqli->real_connect() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Drivers/SimpleConnection.php:54
PHP Warning:  mysqli::real_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Drivers/SimpleConnection.php on line 54
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/sphinxql/src/sphinx.php:0
PHP   2. Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL->execute() /var/www/sphinxql/src/sphinx.php:17
PHP   3. Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL->compile() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/SphinxQL.php:261
PHP   4. Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL->compileSelect() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/SphinxQL.php:399
PHP   5. Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL->compileMatch() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/SphinxQL.php:559
PHP   6. Foolz\SphinxQL\Drivers\SimpleConnection->escape() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/SphinxQL.php:467
PHP   7. Foolz\SphinxQL\Drivers\SimpleConnection->ping() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Drivers/SimpleConnection.php:191
PHP   8. Foolz\SphinxQL\Drivers\SimpleConnection->connect() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Drivers/SimpleConnection.php:80
PHP   9. mysqli->real_connect() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Drivers/SimpleConnection.php:54
PHP Warning:  mysqli::real_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=10605 in /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Drivers/SimpleConnection.php on line 54
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/sphinxql/src/sphinx.php:0
PHP   2. Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL->execute() /var/www/sphinxql/src/sphinx.php:17
PHP   3. Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL->compile() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/SphinxQL.php:261
PHP   4. Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL->compileSelect() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/SphinxQL.php:399
PHP   5. Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL->compileMatch() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/SphinxQL.php:559
PHP   6. Foolz\SphinxQL\Drivers\SimpleConnection->escape() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/SphinxQL.php:467
PHP   7. Foolz\SphinxQL\Drivers\SimpleConnection->ping() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Drivers/SimpleConnection.php:191
PHP   8. Foolz\SphinxQL\Drivers\SimpleConnection->connect() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Drivers/SimpleConnection.php:80
PHP   9. mysqli->real_connect() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Drivers/SimpleConnection.php:54
PHP Warning:  mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Drivers/SimpleConnection.php on line 54
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/sphinxql/src/sphinx.php:0
PHP   2. Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL->execute() /var/www/sphinxql/src/sphinx.php:17
PHP   3. Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL->compile() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/SphinxQL.php:261
PHP   4. Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL->compileSelect() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/SphinxQL.php:399
PHP   5. Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL->compileMatch() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/SphinxQL.php:559
PHP   6. Foolz\SphinxQL\Drivers\SimpleConnection->escape() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/SphinxQL.php:467
PHP   7. Foolz\SphinxQL\Drivers\SimpleConnection->ping() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Drivers/SimpleConnection.php:191
PHP   8. Foolz\SphinxQL\Drivers\SimpleConnection->connect() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Drivers/SimpleConnection.php:80
PHP   9. mysqli->real_connect() /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Drivers/SimpleConnection.php:54
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Foolz\SphinxQL\Exception\ConnectionException: Connection Error: [2006]MySQL server has gone away in /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Drivers/SimpleConnection.php:60
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Drivers/SimpleConnection.php(80): Foolz\SphinxQL\Drivers\SimpleConnection->connect()
#1 /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Drivers/SimpleConnection.php(191): Foolz\SphinxQL\Drivers\SimpleConnection->ping()
#2 /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/SphinxQL.php(467): Foolz\SphinxQL\Drivers\SimpleConnection->escape('(@content \xD0\xB2\xD0\xB0\xD1...')
#3 /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/SphinxQL.php(559): Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL->compileMatch()
#4 /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/SphinxQL.php(399): Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL->compileSelect()
#5 /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/SphinxQL.php(261): Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL->compile()
# in /var/www/sphinxql/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Drivers/SimpleConnection.php on line 60
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

9312 suggests api port. You need the sphinql (mysql based) protocol, somthing like

```
listen = 192.168.1.102:9306:mysql41
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

A better explanation for this situation is that, indeed, Sphinx runs by default on 9312. However, to issue SphinxQL queries to its MySQL server, you should connect to port 9306 instead.

```
$conn->setParams(array('host' => '192.168.1.102', 'port' => 9306));
```

> Tip: currently that Connection class is deprecated. The correct would be using `Foolz\SphinxQL\Drivers\Mysqli\Connection` instead (same API).